# ascii character removal from .tex file

Tags: symbols, search

Hi have used latex for 30 years.  But have a new problem - I've created a .tex file cut-and-pasted from many different files written on a mac using various word processors.  Problem is there are symbols here driving Latex crazy.  For instance ellipsis ...  symbols go to some special character.  Single and double quotes that are curly go to something else etc.  It's a big problem and a few 100 pages.  Seems impossible to change one by one by hand.  Every contraction ' is curly etc.   I need to search and replace.  But how to search for non-standard ascii symbols?  So question is how to search for these special symbols using the texshop editor?  Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to simply copy the first one you see and use that to search for the rest but the symbols should not "drive latex crazy" latex can quite happily typeset left and right quotes elipses and other symbols from their unicode input so you could just leave them where they are assuming you have the files in a consistent encoding such as utf-8.

Comment: There are alternatives such as using XeLaTeX, or with pdflatex, load the [newunicodechar](https://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) package and define whatever you need, e.g., `\newunicodechar{’}{'}` `\newunicodechar{…}{\ldots}` and so on.  But I find that an up to date pdflatex does fine these days with smart punctuation, even without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.